# WSO2 API MGT 2.0 Oracle 11G support

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

According WSO2 API MGT 2.0 [Setting up Oracle](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Setting+up+Oracle), i tried to deploy sample app, but it's blocked, display "deploying". Then, i clicked APIs, the sample api's status is CREATED. I tried to save it, but it reported "Error occurred while updating API" but without detail.

My oracle is **11g**, and master-datasources.xml sample is:

```
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/TEST</url>
                <username>wso2am</username>
                <password>wso2am</password>
                <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>80</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in terminal or wso2carbon.llog file? 
What do you mean by tried to deploy an "app" and it's blocked?

Comment: deploy an "app" means deploy the sample API; It's blocked means the popup message "Sample API is deploying" is always there.

Comment: btw, there are no errors in both terminal and wso2carbon.log file.

Comment: tried both ojdbc14 and ojdbc6, the results are same.

Comment: @EmmanSun, Can try with ojdbc7 Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i make the mistake, i used ojdbc14 at the first time, then used ojdbc6 & ojdbc7, but i did NOT remove related jar in **repository\components\dropins** folder.

***So the lesson is to remove related jars in dropins folder when we update driver.***

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Driver name you have configured is not correct.
Please use the driver name as follows with ojdbc7.jar as the driver.

**oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver** like below.

```
 <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/TEST</url>
                <username>wso2am</username>
                <password>wso2am</password>
                <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>80</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's still not work when i used ojdbc7.jar(and i tried both oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver & oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

The last output in console is as below:

[2016-08-04 15:38:16,240]  INFO - CarbonEventManagementService Starting polling event receivers
[2016-08-04 15:38:16,337]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 0ms